# Tuple unpacking combined with ipython shell escape

Tags: python, bash, ipython, iterable-unpacking

How can I unpack the output of a shell escape in ipython?

Example (works):

```
In [1]: !locate .hgrc
/home/wim/.hgrc
/usr/share/doc/mercurial-common/examples/sample.hgrc

In [2]: hgrcs = !locate .hgrc

In [3]: hgrcs[0]
Out[3]: '/home/wim/.hgrc'
```

But this doesn't work:

```
In [4]: hgrc0, *rest = !locate .hgrc
  File "<ipython-input-4-e8900264b4a8>", line 1
    hgrc0, *rest = !locate .hgrc
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also not working:

```
In [13]: x = !locate .hgrc | head -1

In [14]: x
Out[14]: ['/home/wim/.hgrc']

In [15]: x, = !locate .hgrc | head -1
  File "<ipython-input-15-524d2c9ab16f>", line 1
    x, = !locate .hgrc | head -1
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

IPython 0.13.2 on Python 3.3.2+.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you sure you're in Python 3? Second example seems to work based on my test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved shortly after I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5305) for it.

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/5321

Answer (score 5):

Icky, but for this particular case:

```
hgrc0, _ = !locate .hgrc | head -1 | printf '%s\n_' $(cat)
```

Comment: I’ll keep trying things, but IPython is segfaulting now… [actually, it seems to happen whenever Down is pressed at the end of history]

Comment: Thanks, it works although I don't actually understand what is going on there.  In fact, if there are two lines returned, then a simple unpacking does work (e.g. `x,y = !locate .hgrc`), it is the one-element unpack that doesn't seem to work.  And the splat unpack.

Comment: Well, IPython apparently just doesn’t support that in its own unpacking syntax. (Worthy of a bug filing, maybe?)

Comment: OK, I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5305) on github, lets see what happens.  :)

Comment: @minitech, the segfaulting seems to be a bug in readline 6.3.